# How do i create a message box in blue prism?

Tags: blueprism

I need to create a couple of message boxes in blue prism for a demo.  This is how far I have gotten:

```
1. I am using the code stage
2. In the Inputs tab I have declared my Message and have given it a value
3. In the Code tab I have declared: `MessageBox.Show(Message)`
```

When I validate the code I get a compiler error: "

> 'MessageBox' is not declared "

Guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import `System.Windows.Forms` to your namespace in order to reference the `MessageBox` object the way you currently have in your code.

1. Open the initialize page of your object. Right-click the Description box (located in the upper-left of your page, by default) and select "Properties".
2. Click over to the Code Options tab.
3. Add a Namespace Import by clicking the Add button to the right of the "Namespace Imports" table. Set the new line item's value to "System.Windows.Forms".

Reset and re-run and you should be good to go to use MessageBox().

Comment: Oh  my goodness@esqew it worked...but now my tech arch has asked me to have the button clicked after a 2 second pause.  I researched the ENTER key and added in the Code Tab:  SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") but that doesn't work and I haven't found a method for a 2 second timeout.  Could  you please help with this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RussyG Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a way to have the MessageBox disappear programmatically using simply Blue Prism. You may want to ask a separate question for better visibility.

Comment: I think that you need to attach BP to the msgbox window to send key to it.

Comment: @RAFEL YES!! I  tried to do just that using App Mod but I couldn't spy it.  Any suggestions..Would greatly appreciated it!

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help @esqew !!

Comment: Yes, but did you detach from your "main" Object? You need to detach, the creat new object, just for this MessageBox, attach to it, send key, detach and attach to your original main object.